# Webkit horizontal flexbox tabbing and scrolling

Tags: webkit, flexbox, tabbing

I have a  horizontal flexbox with similar several elements inside. Each  is wrapped in an  to enable tabbing between items. I'm using embedded webkit, so Chrome would be needed to see the effect of what I'm trying to achieve.

I can tab successfully between items, but if an item is too far off to the right of the screen, I would like that item to tab into view. But it doesn't. Example code can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sRGWS/

Which uses this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">

.flexbox {
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
margin: 5px;
}

.item{
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="flexbox">
     <a href=""><div class="item"></div></a>
     <a href=""><div class="item"></div></a>
     <a href=""><div class="item"></div></a>
     <a href=""><div class="item"></div></a>
     <a href=""><div class="item"></div></a>
     <a href=""><div class="item"></div></a>
     <a href=""><div class="item"></div></a>
     <a href=""><div class="item"></div></a>
     <a href=""><div class="item"></div></a>
   </div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</body>
</html>
```